# как сделать плавный выход блока HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать плавное появление блока через секунду после загрузки страницы?

Comment: приведите пример того, что написали уже сами и вам постараются помочь с тем где затык

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 это миллисекунд после которого будет работать анимация(плавное появление блока)

Если нужно дополнение дай знать

```js
let x = document.querySelector(".div")
setTimeout(function(){
  x.style.animation = "fade 1s";
  x.style.opacity = "1"
  },1000)
```

```css
.div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:0;
}
@keyframes fade{
  0%{opacity:0;}
  100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<div class = "div"></div>
```